# Rails' Sandbox like feature in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sandbox

I wonder if there are any features in MySQL that I can manipulate the entire database and when I exit the MySQL no real changes made at the actual database?

The Rails has feature like this called `sandbox`.

Comment: I just googled but surprisingly enough there doesn't appear to be that facility... it's probably easiest for you to make a copy of the database you want to play around with, although appreciate that's not great if you need to reimport 20 times

Comment: Yes, I googled it too. I thought I couldn't come up with a good `name` or `query`, so I asked the question.

Comment: Can you explain a little what the use case is for this question? Is this for testing or development or should it work in production? For instance: do you want to have some kind of dry-run capability for your users?

Comment: @nathanvda It can be used for testings, development and also for productions, for example, you have some queries that manipulate the entire database (e.g. for (pre/post)-processing the database) and you want to see the results of your processing queries' results to the database before you make the actual move.

Comment: Wait I misunderstood your question: you do not want this feature in a rails app, but in mysql? This means you want to run queries without impact, correct? One would use transactions for that, but it depends which db-tool you are using? Some tools autocommit each operation. Rails by default also auto-commits unless you explicitly start a transaction.

Comment: Yes, I want the operation to get done in `MySQL` without actual impacts on the database. I got it, Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html). It's the same Rails is using.